# Extract text from HTML and pass it to MySQL query in a PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I've been looking around for solutions for this for quite sometime and sadly, haven't found a proper solution for it.

Here's the situation.

I have a Bootstrap modal that displays text ( let's call it 'header' ) depending on which button was clicked. The header value is picked up from the data-attribute of the button and using jQuery, I update the text for the respective modal. I hope I've been clear enough about this.

Now, I want to use the same header text in a PHP Script that queries my MySQL table with this 'header' value in the LIKE clause of my query as '%header%'.

Seems simple enough but I can't get my head around it.

Here are some issues that I face:

The header value is empty in the PHP script when I try to pass it to the script. I tried using script_tags to strip the tags around the HTML of the header and just extract the text and also tried PHP DOM but it did not work.

Here are the basic steps for further clarity:

1. I have a PHP script that needs to get a text value from the HTML on the same page.
2. This text value was picked up from a data-attribute of a button and updated via jQuery to the HTML.
3. This text value must be included in the LIKE clause of MySQL query in the PHP script for any updates to the table.

I can handle everything else except the extraction of text and sending it to the PHP script part.

Thank you.

Adding Code for reference:

This is the HTML code that houses the data-attribute:

The $project_title variable was set previously and appended to the button.

```
echo "<a class='delete_icon' data-project_title='$project_title'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i></a>";
```

This is the jQuery code:

```
$('#project_profile_modal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var del_icon = $(event.relatedTarget);
    var project_title = del_icon.data('project_title');
    modal.find('h4').text(project_title);
}
```

This is the excerpt of the PHP script that is relevant:

```
<?php

$result = "SELECT content FROM my_table WHERE content LIKE '%$project_title%';

?>
```

Question is: how do I get the text contained in h4 to $project_title/my LIKE clause.

Comment: Post your code hare so we can able to see what you have done so far

Comment: Show us ur attempt first.

Comment: Trigger the ajax in the event when you display the text in the header. You can just pass the data-attribute through ajax.

Comment: show your jquery code

Comment: You likely need an ID as well as text sent to server. Show the jQuery currently used to get/set the text and the button html. Adding ajax to that is simple enough and then ajax response is added to modal content

Answer (score 0):

Assuming button looks something like:

```
<button class="modal-button" data-text="..." data-row_id="...">
```

Then in click handler you gather all the data and send to server:

```
$('.modal-button').click(function(){
   var data = $(this).data();
   // send to server
   $.post(url, data, function(response){
       // update modal header and content
       $('modal-header-selector').text(data.text);
       $('modal-content-selector').html(response);
   })
})
```